# items show page doesn't render when a user is logged in on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5.1

I get the following in my terminal when I click on an item's show link in my rails app:

```
Started GET "/items/7-water-bottle" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-10-17 
13:00:36 
-0700
Processing by ItemsController#show as HTML
Parameters: {"id"=>"7-water-bottle"}
User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 
2 
ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
Item Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `items`.* FROM `items` WHERE `items`.`id` = 
7 LIMIT 1
Review Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `reviews`.* FROM `reviews` WHERE 
`reviews`.`item_id` = 7
Rendering items/show.html.haml within layouts/application
Item Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `items`.* FROM `items` WHERE `items`.`id` = 
0 LIMIT 1
Rendered items/show.html.haml within layouts/application (6.4ms)
Record not found
Rendering public/404.html
Rendered public/404.html (0.5ms)
```

For some reason it's looking for an item with an id of 0. I don't have this issue when no one is logged in.

If you need more information, let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the id that you are passing in is a string.  Rails is trying to coerce that sting `7-water-bottle` into an integer which will return zero (check in your console).

Are you by chance using the [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) gem?  If so, you should use the `Item.friendly.find(params[:id])` which will search by the slug you have defined instead of trying to search by the integer id.

If this is not the case please include more code and context so we can hunt this issue down!